# Discord.py on authorization have a bot add someone to a server?

Tags: discord.py

Is it possible to have a discord application be authorized specifically for the purpose of adding members to a server and then joining it for them?

Comment: Wdym [discord.py]? dpy is a Python Discord API Wrapper for bots, it won't be helpful with Discord Oauth2 Scopes—which sounds like what you're looking for. The `guilds.join` oauth2 scope should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the user to grant your application the `guilds.join` scope.

As described in the [Discord API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes), you need a bot user already in the server for this (emphasis mine):

> **guilds.join** and bot require you to have a *bot account linked to your application*. Also, in order to add a user to a guild, your bot has to already belong to that guild.

`discord.py`, however, does not have built-in support for this behaviour as far as I'm aware. You'll need to implement the OAuth2-Flow for yourself (Discord themselves have a Python example on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/discord/discord-oauth2-example) that you can take inspiration from)